# Degree of variety over $\mathbb{Q}$ versus over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $V$ be a projective variety (possibly reducible) in $\mathbb{P}^n$ defined over $\mathbb{Z}$.

> What is the relation between the degree of $V$ seen as a variety over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and the degree of $V$ seen as a variety over ${\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p}$ for a prime $p$?

It seems that the degree could fall at some primes, probably finitely many. If true, I would be grateful for a reference of this.

Comment: What do you mean by 'degree'?

Comment: Also, what is your definition of variety over a ring (I've seen some different definitions)? In particular, do you want to assume that $V$ is flat over $\mathbb Z$? If not, you will probably find that things like $\mathbb P^n_{\mathbb F_p} \subset \mathbb P^n_{\mathbb Z}$ become a counterexample.

Comment: I mean the standard degree defined using the Hilbert series or equivalently by counting points in the intersection of $V$ with general subspaces. I am certainly assuming that $V_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is non empty.